# Why does my form redirect to itself rather than redirect to the designated target?

Tags: php, html, redirect, forms, http-post

For some reason, upon clicking submit, my page simply redirects back to an emptied form. I cannot seem to figure out the reason. My only guess is that it's not recognizing the "submit" is true and simply returning to itself via the else clause. However, I've switched the action for the form to a defined URL (eg http://google.com) and had it send me to the target. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have been able to reliably show that is is the action value of my form tag which is not behaving properly.

I performed the following test: I can enter in to either of the conditions for my if/else statement and have that value echo below the conditionals. However, if I try to echo that above the form it returns nothing, but the values I've entered in to the form WILL echo above the form (eg. conferenceName as $_POST['conferenceName'] will echo above the form).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Conference Registration [This Page Not Yet Active]</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cmxform.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" class="cmxform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Example Conference Registration</legend>
            <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceName">Applicant's Name<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceAgencySchool">Agency School<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceAgencySchool" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceAgencyAddress">Agency Address<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePhysicalAddress" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceCity">City<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceCity" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceState">State<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceState" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceZip">Zip<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceZip" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePhone">Phone<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePhone" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceExtension">Extension</label> <input name="conferenceExtension" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceNumberOfAttendees">Number of Attendees<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceNumberOfAttendees" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePointOfContactName">P.o.C. Name<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePointOfContactName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePointOfContactPhone">P.o.C. Cell Phone<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePointOfContactPhone" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePointOfContactEmail">P.o.C. Email<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePointOfContactEmail" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceAdditionalAttendeeInfo">Additional Attendee(s) Info</label> 
                    <textarea name="conferenceAdditionalAttendeeInfo" style="height: 100px; width: 90%; max-width: 90%; min-width: 90%;" wrap="soft"></textarea>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <hr>
            <legend>Method of Payment<em>*</em></legend>
            <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>
                    <label><input name="payment" type="radio" value="Online">Online</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><input name="payment" type="radio" value="At The Door"> At the Door</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Invoice # (If Using Invoice)</label><input name="invoiceNumber" type="text">
                </li>
            </ol>
            <hr>
        </fieldset><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Application">
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"]) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferenceName"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferenceAgencySchool"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferencePhysicalAddress"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferenceCity"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferenceState"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferenceZip"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferencePhone"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferenceNumberOfAttendees"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferencePointOfContactName"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferencePointOfContactPhone"])) &&
            (!empty($_POST["conferencePointOfContactEmail"]))
        )
        {
        $action="http://example.net/form-submit.php";
        }
        else
        {
        $action = '"<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"';
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output after following the suggestions you kind folks have provided.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0044)http://example.net/conference-registration.php -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Conference Registration [This Page Not Yet Active]</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Conference Registration [This Page Not Yet Active]_files/cmxform.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" class="cmxform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Example Conference Registration</legend>
            <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceName">Applicant's Name<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceAgencySchool">Agency School<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceAgencySchool" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceAgencyAddress">Agency Address<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePhysicalAddress" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceCity">City<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceCity" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceState">State<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceState" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceZip">Zip<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceZip" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePhone">Phone<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePhone" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceExtension">Extension</label> <input name="conferenceExtension" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceNumberOfAttendees">Number of Attendees<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferenceNumberOfAttendees" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePointOfContactName">P.o.C. Name<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePointOfContactName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePointOfContactPhone">P.o.C. Cell Phone<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePointOfContactPhone" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferencePointOfContactEmail">P.o.C. Email<em>*</em></label> <input name="conferencePointOfContactEmail" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="conferenceAdditionalAttendeeInfo">Additional Attendee(s) Info</label> 
                    <textarea name="conferenceAdditionalAttendeeInfo" style="height: 100px; width: 90%; max-width: 90%; min-width: 90%;" wrap="soft"></textarea>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <hr>
            <legend>Method of Payment<em>*</em></legend>
            <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>
                    <label><input name="payment" type="radio" value="Online">Online</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><input name="payment" type="radio" value="At The Door"> At the Door</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Invoice # (If Using Invoice)</label><input name="invoiceNumber" type="text">
                </li>
            </ol>
            <hr>
        </fieldset><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Application">
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="./Conference Registration [This Page Not Yet Active]_files/si.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: the line near the bottom, should that not be `$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`?

Comment: Paste the rendered html code.

Comment: Added the HTML output after the suggestions were implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You are enclosing PHP echo within quotes which is wrong way of doing in the following line:

```
$action = '"<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"';
```

This code will return only `""`.

Change it to

```
$action = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "#" or assign $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] in action variable.